# Issue with .htaccess rewrite when missing second variable

Tags: .htaccess

I've written this short piece of php code that requires 2 variables name and id, now the code itself works as intended and is not my problem, the problem is that I want to shorten the link to this file from 'http://www.mypage.org/folder/index.php?name=name&id=0' to 'http://www.mypage.org/folder/name;0', like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+);(.*)$ index.php?name=$1&id=$2
```

But if someone enters a link like 'http://www.mypage.org/folder/name' with out the ';' separator they get a 404 page.

**Is there a way to write a sort of if statement that also checks for links with out the ';'?**

The php page can handle a missing id by defaulting to '0' as well as a missing name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `;0` part or URL optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:;(.*))?$ index.php?name=$1&id=$2
```

or like this (if the above does not work in Apache)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(;(.*))?$ index.php?name=$1&id=$3
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution worked as intended, the second one totally ignored the id. I wasn't aware of this little trick.